# How to improve std::vector parameter passing (move semantics?)

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

It seems that I cannot completely understand move semantics: I want to fill an `std::vector` (member of a class) from an external function. Currently, I have something like:

```
void fillVector(MyClass & myclass) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    /* Filling vec */
    // ...
    myclass.setVector(vec);
}

class MyClass {
    public:
         setVector(const std::vector<int> & v) { v_ = v;}
    private:
         std::vector<int> v_;
};

int main() {
    MyClass myclass;
    fillVector(myclass);
    /* Use myclass.v_ somehow */.
}
```

I had this code for a long time, and it works fine. Now, I cannot understand how it works since I am asigning a reference to a vector which will be destroyed. My questions are:

1. How is this code able to work?
2. What is the best way to implement `fillVector` and `MyClass::setVector()`? I think that can be done with move semantics but I cannot figure out how.

Thank you!

Comment: You are not "assigning a reference". You are always *evaluating expressions* and the result of an expression is a *value*, which is always an object and never a reference.

Comment: You've said "move semantics" in the question title, the first sentence, and the tags ... but this question has nothing to do with move semantics! (Except right at the end where you say you think it could be used)

Comment: @JonathanWakely because my questions assumes that the best way to implement this (and the most important question) is using move semantics.

Comment: But your actual question is "how does this work?" and relates to code that doesn't using move semantics **at all**. Just sticking "maybe I could use move semantics" at the end doesn't make it a question about move semantics. Maybe you should understand how the existing code works before you try changing it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely How about now? I edited the title, it might be more descriptive now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why the code works:

The scope of `vec` is the body of `fillVector`. Inside this entire scope, `vec` is perfectly valid. This includes the call to `setVector`. `v` (the parameter of `setVector`) is a reference which binds to `vec`. The body of `setVector` *copies* the contents of the vector `vec` (accessed as `v`) into `v_`. That's an actual copy of data, no reference assignment. Only after `setVector` ends does `fillVector` end, at which point `vec` is destroyed. But it was already copied, so all is well.

How to use move semantics:

You could provide an extra overload of `setVector` which will take an rvalue reference:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  // ...
  void setVector(std::vector<int> &&v) { v_ = std::move(v); }
  // ...
};
```

Then, *move* `vec` into `setVector`:

```
void fillVector(MyClass & myclass) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    /* Filling vec */
    // ...
    myclass.setVector(std::move(vec));
}
```

This will invoke the rvalue overload instead of the lvalue one, and the data will be moved, not copied.

However, perhaps a better interface would be to refactor `fillVector` so that it returns the vector by value, using move semantics automatically:

```
std::vector<int> fillVector() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    /* Filling vec */
    // ...
    return vec;  // Note that a move automatically happens here, or even NRVO
}

int main() {
    MyClass myclass;
    myclass.setVector(fillVector());
    /* Use myclass.v_ somehow */.
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! It works, I was missing the `std::move(vec)` when calling `setVector()`. The refactoring option was discarded because in my real code the return value is a bool to check the state.

Comment: @Yakk Not if you want to keep the const reference overload as well. The const reference overload will [probably perform better in the case of lvalues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64&t=1h03m44s) because it can re-use any existing capacity of `v_`.

Answer (score 1):

vector::operator= assigns contents, and doesn't just link to existing items. When you do v_ = v, v_ gets a new copy of everything in v. Once v is destroyed, the items in v_ still exist.

An easy way to test this and see this in action is to make changes to one of the items in v_[i] and see then print out both v[i] and v_[i]. They will be different.

I don't see anything wrong with your implementation of setVector and fillVector. Is there something in particular you're trying to achieve?